expo react native , @react-native-firebase/app I got this error Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()
i was using expo react native
ive install the firebase package using npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
i also install the package im using @react-native-firebase/analytics
the issue is when ever i try to use this i got  error
<Button
        title="Add To Basket"
        onPress={async () =>
          await analytics().logEvent('basket', {
            id: 3745092,
            item: 'mens grey t-shirt',
            description: ['round neck', 'long sleeved'],
            size: 'L',
          })
        }
      />

by clicking it i got this error :

Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

same thing from their documentation but is not working
import react, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Check analy"
        onPress={async () =>
          await analytics().logSelectContent({
            content_type: 'clothing',
            item_id: 'abcd',
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}


Did you call initializeApp anywhere in your app?  If so where?  Can you verify that you called it (because error message is clear that you didn't). Please edit the question to show these details and add more debugging information that we can use to duplicate the result.

I found out that I was skipping the section that required me to add some code to the native files, according to the documentation there is no need to initializeApp because is already done in the package
